# How to execute postman collection using newman.js for entire data?

Tags: node.js, postman, newman

i am trying to execute postman collection using `newman.js` because i need to extract the response and save to a file, below is the script i am using for that

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    newman = require('newman'),
    results = [];

newman.run({
        reporters: 'cli',
        collection: '/Users/prasad/Documents/migration/export_uuid_emails.postman_collection.json',
        iterationData: '/Users/prasad/Documents/migration/test.csv',
        //data: '/Users/prasad/Documents/migration/test.csv', // this also doesn't work
        iterationCount: 1,
        //iterationCount: 2, // this is iterting the same data two times
        environment: '/Users/prasad/Documents/migration/stage.postman_environment.json'
}).on('request', function(err, args) {
        if(!err) {
                var rawBody = args.response.stream,
                 body = rawBody.toString();

                results.push(JSON.parse(body));
        }
}).on('done', function(err, summary) {
        fs.writeFileSync('migration-report.json', JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
});
```

below is the contents of `test.csv`

```
userId
0e4aab3a-62cb-4e23-8f44-40b1f1c5f9eb
a1d3e402-a83f-4918-9b7c-333d281be35d
```

below is the environment file

```
{
    "id": "8e50b25f-df1a-4c15-abe9-1f8e4728da13",
    "name": "stage",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "baseUrl",
            "value": "https://stage.api.auth.aws.pen.com",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "accountStatus",
            "value": "active",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2020-03-16T10:51:49.468Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/7.20.0"
}
```

According to the script it should execute for two userId's but it is always executing for only first userId, i tried with iterationCount with 2 but it's executing same id two times.
i followed [newman documentation](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#api-reference) and a [this reference](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3033#issuecomment-301758179)

 Can any one please help me on this ?

Thanks,
Prasad

Comment: I have a simplified version of your script running locally and it's working fine for me with 2 iterations. Each one is picking up the different id and writing the response to the file.

Comment: Which version of Newman are you using? Are there are `userId` references in the environment file as those would be using in the request due to the way the variable scope works?

Comment: i have updated the environment file and i am using 4.6.0 version for newman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying in different ways then i figured that it's because of `iterationCount: 1` when i changed that to `iterationCount: 0` it started working. 
 Even if you don't provide `iterationCount` whenever you are providing `iterationData` then it is working.
Below is my understanding
No.of entries in `test.csv` file are 3
So it's choosing those many no.of entries which is equal to `iterationCount` if you don't specify any value then it's looping all entries which is 3 in this case.

i hope it will helpful for some other people